# How to insert with table creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a more appropriate way to execute several inserts into a nonexistent table. 
To create the table beforehand is not easily possible, as I don't know the data type of the selected column.
An "insert with create" would do, but I don't think there is anything like that.

Is there any better way to do so than to select into and then to insert?

Here is the "bad" way I do it, in an example very much stripped down to demonstrate the problem.

```
set nocount on

declare 
    @name sysname = '',
    @i int = 0,
    @sql nvarchar(4000) = ''

declare test cursor for 
    select top 10 a.name from sys.tables a inner join sys.columns b on a.object_id = b.object_id --and b.name = 'description' 
open test
fetch next from test into @name
while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
begin

    if @i = 0 begin


        set @sql = 'select distinct top 10 description into #t1 from ' + @name + ''
        select @sql
        --  exec sp_executesql @sql

    end
    else begin

        set @sql = 'insert #t1 select distinct top 10 description into #t1 from ' + @name + ''
        select @sql
        --  exec sp_executesql @sql

    end
    set @i = @i + 1
    fetch next from test into @name
end
close test
deallocate test

if object_id ('tempdb..#t1') is not null select * from #t1
```

This solution is "bad" as you need the statement at two positions. In the case shown here this is trivial, but when the statement gets more complex this can become an issue.

Comment: Why doesn't `select . . . into` do what you want?

Comment: Something is a bit off here. You say you don't know the datatype but you have a column named description on every single table? If you know you have a column named description on every table why do you change the datatype between tables?

Comment: @Sean Lange: I have to read from data, that is not under my responsibility. There might be changes without anouncement.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Select .. into would only do in the first loop. The next loop should be an insert.

Comment: It is still rather bizarre. Why do you need to copy the top 10 rows into a temp table from a table that you don't know the columns? And then you have top 10 but no order by so you just get 10 random rows. I can't come up with any kind of business reason where this would be useful.

Comment: The problem is just striped down to an example. There are some thousand tables and they all have more than 100 Mio. rows. The real statement is something like 2000 lines and I don't like to double it for an select..into and an insert.! Maybe no good busioness reason anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query into this one:

```
set nocount on

declare 
    @name sysname = '',
    @i int = 0,
    @sql nvarchar(4000) = N''

if object_id ('tempdb..#t1') is not null DROP TABLE #t1

;WITH cte AS (
    select top 10 a.[name]
    from sys.tables a 
    inner join sys.columns b 
        on a.object_id = b.object_id --and b.name = 'description' 
)

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'UNION ALL 
select distinct top 10 description 
from ' + QUOTENAME([name])  + CHAR(13)
FROM cte

SELECT @sql = N';WITH cte AS (' + STUFF(@sql,1,10,') SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM cte')

PRINT @sql
--EXEC (@sql)

select * from #t1
```

- No cursor or while loop;
- Temporary table is dropped (if exists) before query execution;

You got a weird query, as for now it takes the first table from `sys.tables` and `SELECT TOP 10 Descriptions` from this table as many times as there are columns in this table.

Comment: Using a CTE in this case is a nice idea but does not solve the problem. Your idea: Build one statement and use "select into". OK, but this gets hard to handle if the statement is large or you have a lot of loops. As far as I know you are limited to a length of 4000 for a single literal, what is not to much for a more complex SQL-statement.

Comment: You can use nvarchar(max), limit is 2GB. Read about sp_executesql on MSDN. If you refer to 4k chars problem with concatination - it is solved with same nvarchar(max).

Comment: Even if you use nvarchar(max) there is a limit with a single literal that is limited to 4000/8000 characters.

Comment: Well, I already checked this on 2012, 2014 and 2016 servers. It executes large querys, more then 100k charecters.

Comment: Alwayse a good idea to doublecheck old judgements. You are perfectly right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT INTO statement copies data from one table into a new table, this might help you.

Example:-

SELECT *
INTO newtable 
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition

The above also supports joins.